# Read Framerate from Header in PHP or JS

Tags: php, javascript, mp4, frame-rate

Is there any way to read the framerate of an mp4 file with php or javascript without having access to shell (no system() etc.)

I thought of readfile or fopen, but i just can't find anything on google or php.net.

Comment: Is the file stored client side or server side?

Comment: There is no thing like a single framerate in an mp4 file I'd say. The mp4 format is just a container holding other formats. Multiple objects might be contained.

Comment: There is a class for this, have a try: [php-mp4info](http://code.google.com/p/php-mp4info/)

Comment: @arkascha I believe the OP is referring to MP4s that store video data. And since in H264 (the most common codec in MP4s nowadays) doesn't have framerate info in its raw stream, it must be in the container.